# Though I have added Git key in TortoiseGit, Asking password of SSH host everytime

Tags: key, tortoisegit

TortoiseGit asking password everytime while pulling or pushing code changes even though I have added Git key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please use the following steps to resolve such problems:**

1. Remove the old ssh-key from server and re-add the key. (`/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`).
2. Then restart the `SSH` service. (`service sshd restart`)